# Run the codes in posts with a button

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code

Recently I saw a post on StackOverflow in which a code snippet could be run by pressing a button.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380104/c-drawing-scatter-plot-on-ms-charts

[image]

It was indeed really helpful. I brought the link in TeX/LaTeX chatroom and I found that David Carlisle has already developed a very useful and similar code which allows run of the LaTeX codes. The feature is being used in [latex.org](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=34570) forums. The link to the code is [this](https://texlive.net/run?).

Is there anyway to add such feature to our site too? It is very handy and useful, specifically when the codes are small and need just a click to see the results. No need to copy it to the editor environment and running it on the system.

[image]

Comment: as far as I can see stack code snippets are not hosted so they only work with javascript running in the browser of the reader. You say the the C# example that you link to was "helpful" but does it work at all, I don't see it running C#?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is not running for the C#. It works for JS. But I can see how helpful it is if we have it on TeX.SE. It was useful to see the button there. Maybe I have used the wrong sentence, but I find that post useful because it gave me the idea that a button can appear under pieces of code and show something about the codes, possibly how they look or how they may run.

Comment: but that just highlights why doing it for tex is hard. Most people are reading this site using a browser that implements a javascript engine so running a javascript code snippet requires no external software and no site and security concerns accepting random code from the internet, running it on the server machine and returning the result.  Running tex or running C# requires a lot more infrastructure. and someone has to pay for a host that can run potentially thousands of simultaneous tex jobs.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz it does although one thing that has changed since the answers there is that the usage of texlive.net at latex.org and related forums shows that it is quite practical to do and not completely bad, although possibly the bandwidth from this site would increase the server requirements above what the current texlive.net provides. (did you decide not to do this at topanswers?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is a feature request to add this at topanswers.